# href-links in search result tabs not working due to umlaut characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There is a problem with two tabs above
the list of search results in my company's search site finna.nu (The website and search engine were not developed by me), and
it has to do with umlaut characters (ä and ö) and the href-links in the tabs.

Depending on what you search, three tabs can show up:

1. Produkt/tjänst (href is "https://finna.nu/?sok=&sokvad=rekrytering&sokvar=&sokb=#Produkt/tj%C3%A4nst")
2. Bransch (href is "https://finna.nu/?sok=&sokvad=rekrytering&sokvar=&sokb=#Bransch")
3. Företag (Company) (href is "https://finna.nu/?sok=&sokvad=rekrytering&sokvar=&sokb=#F%C3%B6retag")

"Produkt/tjänst" and "Företag" don't work.

Nothing happens when you click on the company-tab. When you switch back to the product-tab, you get this message in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #Produkt/tjänst
> at fa.error (jquery-bootstrap.js:2:12733)

It uses an outdated version of jQuery (1.12.2) and jQuery UI (1.12.1).

The code for the tabs looks like this:

```
$.each(data, function()
{
head = arguments[0];
/* if (String('<?php echo $_GET['sokvad']; ?>').toLowerCase() == 'finnerboda kommun') {
    $('body').removeClass( "finna" ).addClass( "finnerboda" );
}*/
if (head == 'cssclass') {
 if (this.length == 0) {
   $('body').attr( 'class', 'finna' );
 }
 else {
   $('body').attr( 'class', this );
 }
 return true;
}

head = head.substr(0, 5) + count;
$('ul#tabs').append('<li><a data-toggle="pill" class="pillbg" href="#' + head + '">' + arguments[0] + ' (' + this.count + ' tr&auml;ffar)</a></li>');

if (head == 'Prod' + count)
  {
    sokord = this.count;
  }

if (head == 'F&#246;re' + count)
  {
    foretag = this.count;
  }

if (head == 'Bran' + count)
  {
    bransch = this.count;
  }
```

I tried updating jQuery to version 2 and 3 but that didn't solve the problem.

I included "`header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");`" in the opening php tag of the source code but that made no difference.

I have used console logging.

I have experimented and made various changes to the code to find the solution through trial and error and nothing has worked.

I tried replacing the logical operator (==) with "===" for "företag" to see if it would fix the problem with the interpretation of umlaut characters and make the href link work but it didn't.

EDIT: Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
<?php ini_set('memory_limit', '768M'); header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" type="application/javascript">
        
var pagedata;
var count = 0;
var tabcount = [];

function MakeItem(object) {
 if (object === Object(object)) {
  return    '<div class="panel panel-default">' +
   /* div that contains info about the object in search result list */
    '</div>';
     } else { return '...';}
}

var glbstart = 0;

function GetData(start) {
  glbstart = start;

 var ajx = $.post('./api/dosearch.php',
 {

  sokvad: "<?php echo $_GET['sokvad']; ?>",
  sokvar: "<?php echo $_GET['sokvar']; ?>",
  limit: glbstart

 }, "json").always(function(data) {
  if (glbstart == 0) {
     $('ul#tabs').empty();
     $('div#tabcontents').empty();        
  }
  if (($.isEmptyObject(data)) && (glbstart == 0)) {
     $('#msg').html("No match in the database!");
  }
  else {
  if (glbstart == 0)
 {
 $('#msg').empty();

  var head = '';
  var content;
  pagedata = data;
  var reclimit;
  var countres = 0;

  var sokord = 0;
  var foretag = 0;
  var bransch = 0;

$.each(data, function() {
  head = arguments[0];

  <?php echo $_GET['sokvad']; ?>

  if (head == 'cssclass') {
   if (this.length == 0) {
    $('body').attr( 'class', 'finna' );
  } else {
    $('body').attr( 'class', this );
  }
  return true;
  }

  $('ul#tabs').append('<li id="pilltab"><a data-toggle="pill" class="pillbg" href="#' + head + '">' + arguments[0] + ' (' + this.count + ' tr&auml;ffar)</a></li>');
                                   
if (head == 'Prod' + count){
sokord = this.count;
}

if (head == 'F&#246;re' + count){
foretag = this.count;
}

if (head == 'Bran' + count){
bransch = this.count;
}

content = document.createElement('div');
$(content).attr('id', head).height(700).attr('class', 'infinitescroll tab-pane fade in').attr('srcel', arguments[0]).infinitescroll(
 {
  //dataSource is required to append additional content
  dataSource: function(helpers, callback) {
   var activetabcontent = $("#tabcontents").children("div.active");

   if (tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] + 1 < pagedata[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')].count) 
   { 
     if (tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] == pagedata[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')].result.length-1) { 
      GetData(pagedata[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')].result.length).then(
       function(){ 
        tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] = tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] + 1;
       callback({
      content: MakeItem(pagedata[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')].result[tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')]])
     });
    },

 function() { // GetData failed
  callback ({ end: true });
 }

 );
 } else { 
    // Retrieve from local variable
    tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] = tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')] + 1;
    // $('#msg').text(tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')]);
    callback
     ({ content: MakeItem(pagedata[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')].result[tabcount[activetabcontent.attr('srcel')]])  });
 }
} else {
     callback ({ end: true });
}
 }
 }
);
document.getElementById('tabcontents').appendChild(content);

var reclimit = 0;

$.each(this.result, function() {
 if (reclimit == 10) { return true; }
  count = count + 1;
  $(content).append(MakeItem(this));
  reclimit = reclimit + 1;
});

tabcount[arguments[0]] = reclimit;
 countres = countres + this.length;
});

if ((sokord == 0) && (bransch < foretag)) {
 $('ul#tabs').children(':first').addClass('active');
 $('div#tabcontents').children(':first').addClass('active');
}

else if ((sokord == 0) && (foretag < bransch)) {
 $('ul#tabs').children(':last').addClass('active');
 $('div#tabcontents').children(':first').addClass('active');
}

else {
 $('ul#tabs').children(':first').addClass('active');
 $('div#tabcontents').children(':first').addClass('active');
}

} // start=0
else
{
//$('#msg').append('Hamtat mera');
$.each(data, function(){
  var list = '';
  list = arguments[0];

  $.merge(pagedata[list].result, this.result);
   });
  }
 }
 });
 return ajx;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 GetData(0);
});

</script>
        
<div id="sok-page-container" class="container fuelux well">
            
 <!-- // Top searchform -->
 <div class="row sform mobile">
  <div class="speedsearch">
   <ul id="content"></ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="tabplatta" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
  <br />
   <div id="content" class="col-lg-12">
    <span id="msg" class="" style="font-weight:bold;color:#FF0000;"></span>
    <ul class="tabs-menu nav nav-pills" id="tabs"></ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabcontents"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `count` defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: count is set to 0 and is located above all functions.

Comment: I see the update yet I am still unable to replicate the issue. It does not indicate what version of jQuery and jQuery UI are being used. I do not have access to `common.js` so I cannot use any of that and I cannot determine if there are any conflicts with that code. Please refine your example of your issue to just the **Minimal** code needed to replicate the issue.

Comment: I have examined `common.js`. There are no conflicts with the code in that file so i have removed that link.